# configuring shadowbox?

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I'm using shadow box - everything is working fine but I have two uses for it on one page one is a gallery where people scroll through images continuously and the other is an iframe for a form.

how do I remove the next and previous button from the iframe but not the gallery

```
Shadowbox.init({
    displayCounter: false,
    continuous: true <- need to disable for iframe only
});
```

iframe:

```
<a rel="shadowbox[contact];width=420;height=520" href="contact.php?profileID=">Click here</a>
```

gallery

```
<a rel="shadowbox[trader]" href="<?php echo $images[0]; ?>">Click here</a>
<a rel="shadowbox[trader]" href="<?php echo $images[1]; ?>">Click here</a>
<a rel="shadowbox[trader]" href="<?php echo $images[2]; ?>">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look into the [docs](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/api.html) and the [usage section](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html)? You don't need multiple scripts - that would only cause problems and is completely unnecessary.

Instead, leave the `init()` function alone and use the `setup()` function. Something like this should work (for this snippet to work you need the according class on you links):

```
Shadowbox.init({
    displayCounter: false
});

Shadowbox.setup("a.noniframe", {
      continuous: true
});

Shadowbox.setup("iframe a", {
      continuous: false
});
```